# How to "source" (not run line by line) an R script from the Windows command line

Tags: r, windows, batch-file, rscript

I am creating an R script `myscript.R` which manipulates an excel file by means of `XLConnect`package.
The point is it refers to several external files: the excel file itself and another R file (functions library), so I need to set a working directory in the location of the script (so that relative paths to external files work properly).
I am using the following in my script

```
new_wd <- dirname(sys.frame(1)$ofile)
setwd(new_wd)
```

When I source the script from my RStudio it gets the job done. The problem is that the script is to be used by non-programmers, non-Rstutio-users, so I create .bat file (which I want to turn into an .exe one)

```
"C:\Program Files\R\R-4.0.3\bin\Rscript.exe" "C:\my\path\to\myscript.R"
```

It executes the script line by line but `sys.frame(1)` only works when sourcing.

How could I solve it?

Thanx

Comment: There's absolutely no need, nor is it wise, to create a batch file, to 'turn into an .exe'. All the .exe would do would be to place the actual batch file into a, probably randomly generated, temporary location, and run it from there as a batch file. Just use the batch file exactly as it is, you will then be able to specifically define it a known location, and therefore the paths relative to it. You will probably also need to cater for the possibility that each of your end users will be unlikely to have `rscript.exe` installed to the same location, or have it defined within their environments.

Comment: Thank you. I thought it would be easier for my final users. Now I see what you tell me about the relative paths depending on the location of the .bat.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution and it works properly.
From `CMD` command line or from a `.bat` file one can add an argument `-e` to the command, so that you can use a R language.

```
absolute\path\to\Rscript.exe -e "source('"relative\path\to\myscript.R"')"
```

It worked for me.
Besides, as Compo commented, I think there's no need for a `.exe` file, since a `.bat` does the job.

Comment: I could run making: `absolute\path\to\Rscript.exe -e "source('relative\path\to\myscript.R')"`